# google tag assistant Warning: Missing quotes around the string values of the object

Tags: google-tag-manager

Hi I'm getting the error

> Warning: Missing quotes around the string values of the object.

From Google Tag assistant on checkout success page.
This error is not mentioned on the page this message is linked to

https://support.google.com/tagassistant/answer/2978937?ref_topic=2947092

All values look correct, there are only 7 including duplicates in all

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var google_tag_params = {
ecomm_prodid: ['1111111','2222222'],
ecomm_pagetype: 'purchase',
ecomm_totalvalue: 123.99,
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id       = 9999999999;
var google_conversion_label    = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY";
var google_conversion_value    = 123.99;
var google_remarketing_only    = true;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img id="google_dynamic_remarketing" height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/9999999999/?label=YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY&value=123.99&guid=ON&script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

Comment: the last item of an object shouldn't have a comma:
ecomm_totalvalue: 123.99, -> remove this one

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/3103357#check_tag) on `ecomm_totavalue` is conflicting. Some instances show it with quotes and others without quotes. Data collection for value should work regardless of whether there are quotes around the value itself.

Tag Assistant is treating all parameters the same and asking for quotes around the value associated with each parameter -- including the `ecomm_totalvalue`.

I'll see if this is a quick fix for the extension or may take longer to set different checks for different variables..

Comment: I guess the same issue still exists?